# Scaling services with database

Tags: database, scaling, steeltoe

how does Steeltoe handles scaling services with there own database?
For example I've got a search service and want to scale it up, because the user requests getting more.
Scaling up the service is not enough, because the bottleneck is the database. More search service instances reading the same database. Normally you have to replicate the database.

Is there a way Steeltoe can manage this?

BR
Marco

Answer (score 0):

Scaling of databases is beyond the scope of anything Steeltoe (or likely any library AFAIK) is intended for.

If your DB is your bottleneck and you can't fix it by tuning indexes and queries, scale it up or out as needed.